# How to load proj4 for lat/long in highmaps using typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, proj

I would like to reproduce [this](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon) highmaps example in react using typescript. However, the lat/long points are not being displayed which seems related to proj4 package as it is working in this javascript [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nkbx2auw/1/).

I have tried it in a [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/91kn3w37w). If I load the package as follows, it is not used but I do not know where it should be called:

```
import * as proj4 from "proj4";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highcharts needs that the `proj4` library should be available on `window`, so you can create your own file which exports that package as a module, and which will have the code below:

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.proj4 = window.proj4 || proj4;
}

export default proj4;
```

Save it to the other file e.g. 'proj4-module.js' and then import it like that:

```
import './proj4-module'
```

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/m4o2q0pzzy

Answer (score 1):

import * as proj4_ from 'proj4';
const proj4 = proj4_.default;

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use proj4 property
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.proj4

Example:

```
import proj4 from "proj4";
import highcharts from "highcharts";
import mapInit from "highcharts/modules/map";

mapInit(highcharts);

const chartOptions: highcharts.Options = {
            chart: {
                type: "map",
                map: "mexico",
                proj4: proj4,                
            }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For better or for worse, it looks like Highmaps expects proj4 to be defined on the global object.  Just add this line of code:

```
(window as any).proj4 = proj4;
```

Comment: That works in the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/91kn3w37w). However, locally it throws the following error: `TypeError: v.proj4 is not a function`

Comment: Try changing the import to `import proj4 from "proj4"` or `import proj4 = require("proj4")`.  Hopefully one of those two will work depending on your build configuration.  What a mess...

Comment: Well now I am getting: `TS1192: Module '".../node_modules/@types/proj4/index"' has no default export.`. Really seems a mess...

Comment: Did you try `import proj4 = require("proj4")`?  Also try with the `esModuleInterop` compiler option set to true or false.  We'll find the magic combination of options.  Or publish a repository and I'll fiddle with it.

Comment: I did try, but then it yields: `TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.` Setting `esModuleInterop` to true neither helps.

Comment: Did the other answer work for you?  (I don't see what's different about it.)  If not, one more guess: go back to `import * as proj4 from "proj4"` and then do `console.log(proj4)` and see what's in there.  You may need to do something like `(window as any).proj4 = proj4.proj4`.  If that still doesn't work, I'm going to need a repository to help any further.

Comment: Yes, the other answer works for me that is why I have accepted it.